# Database Design: separating reusable & instance data

Tags: database-design

I'm developing an app which is basically a collection of checklists that have to be processed. I obviously need a database in which the information has to be stored. I just can't wrap my head around designing the database model.

Following should be considered:

- A checklist-item describes what needs to be checked and should be able to take in different types of input, like simply checking off, radio input (yes/no), some textinput or a dropdownlist of possible values
- A category consists of 0..* sub-categories and/or 0..* items
- A checklist consists of 1..* categories

Obviously these 3 entities have more information like title and description for all of them or modified_by and modified_on for the items, but I'm going to leave that out to keep it short.

The categories, items and some checklists will be predefined and managed from a webinterface

- When an item or a category is updated or deleted, this changes should effect all active checklists that contain these
- A collection of checklist-templates has to be stored, to be provided in the app

In the app:

- Every user can create a checklist by selecting a checklist-template or combining pre-defined categories in the app
- The created checklist can then be worked on, which just means finishing all items

This is a rough mockup of the first draft I came up with. 
[image: first draft]

Eventually I realized, that this doesn't work because there is no separation between the predefined data for reuse and the values that originate from working on a checklist. I figured I need to split the data. this is what I came up with.

[image: second draft]

This way I'd save the changing data for the checklists and items separately from the information that is being reused in multiple checklists. Also I'd add a `is_template` column to the checklist which would enable me to save all predefined and user-created checklists in one table and possibly mark a checklist as a template afterwards, if proven useful.

Now to finish off with some questions:
Is there a flaw that I'm missing in this approach?
Does somebody know a better way to design this?
Did it even become clear what I'm trying to do and why I'm having issues with this?

Please let me know. It's been a while since I did database modeling and this is supposed to be only the beginning of a larger tool, so it needs a good foundation.

Comment: Naming all your columns with `id` is kind of confusing.

Comment: I had to add at least one column to add the foreign keys, which is a restriction of MySQL Workbench. So I chose a simple `id`. Also it doesn't show the foreign keys as columns, but as labels for the relations.

Comment: What are you going for with subcategories?  Is the idea that if you pick a category all of its descendants come along automatically, but sometimes you want just a subcategory and not a whole category?  Also, how were you planning on distinguishing between a template and an instance of a checklist in your second model?

Comment: 1) Right, sometimes I want the checklist to only have "top level" categories, and every now and then I want one of these to have subcategories. 2) The `checklist_data` table would have a reference to all the instances. The `checklist` table would have all checklist configurations, with the option to mark it as a template. Thats what I meant with the `is_template` above.